# Cannot refer child view on <include> through android data binding

Tags: android, data-binding, include

I am new to android data binding . I am unable to refer the child view of

cannot do **binding.inHeader.tvTryAgain**

When trying to access child view of `inHeader` i can't get any suggestion of generated id's by `Android data binding`

main.xml

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:background="@drawable/im_bg_sign_up">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/in_header"
            layout="@layout/header_title_activity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</include>
</RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

header_title_activity.xml

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/li_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/re_error_message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/re_title"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:background="@color/grey_normal"
            android:visibility="gone">


            <com.bigstar.tv.view.TextviewNormal
                android:id="@+id/tv_error_message"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_try_again"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Please fill in all the details to continue signing up"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_small"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:typeface="normal" />

            <com.bigstar.tv.view.TextviewNormal
                android:id="@+id/tv_try_again"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="@string/retry"
                android:textColor="@color/cyan1"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_small"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:typeface="normal"
                android:visibility="gone" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

Comment: It may be a bug in Android Studio that it isn't being refreshed. If you type it and recompile, does it work anyway?

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood your question correctly i guess u want to add "include.xml" in your include tag in main.xml .
For that modify your include part as:

```
<include
            android:id="@+id/in_header"
            layout="@layout/include"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</include>
```

Comment: its just an copy pasted code . sorry for that .. I am using layout="@layout/include" already . Edited the post

Comment: when you inflate(R.layout.main) you should be able to findViewById for all Ids(eg : tv_error_message) by (Rid.tv_error_message) in header_title_activity. Sometimes it happens in IDE that we dont get suggestions.Please paste your java code for more clarification

Answer (score 0):

Remove the underscore in the id tag and try to clean

```
android:id="@+id/inHeader"
```